# Better way to write nested try except python

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

Is there a better way for me to write this without nesting it like this?

```
try:
    if find_path(graph, startPos, (targetX+1,targetY,targetX,targetY)):
        print('YES')
except:
    try:
        if find_path(graph, startPos, (targetX,targetY+1,targetX,targetY)):
            print('YES')
    except:
        try:
            if find_path(graph, startPos, (targetX-1,targetY,targetX,targetY)):
                print('YES')
        except:
            try:
                if find_path(graph, startPos, (targetX,targetY-1,targetX,targetY)):
                    print('YES')
            except:
                print('NO')
```

Comment: You can use what is called a "Nested Try Block"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of potential coordinates, and then try them each in turn, in a for loop, breaking the loop on success:

```
success = "NO"
coords = ((targetX+1,targetY), (targetX,targetY+1), (targetX-1,targetY), (targetX,targetY-1))

for coord in coords:
    try:
        x, y = coord
        find_path(graph, startPos, (x, y, targetX,targetY))
    except:
        pass
    else:
        # Set success state and break out of the for loop
        success = "YES"
        break
print(success)
```